# Custom useragent in nightwatch

Tags: selenium-webdriver, user-agent, nightwatch.js

Is there a way to set a custom useragent for just one test in nightwatch?

I want to test a page using both mobile and non-mobile useragents to ensure the proper experience is shown.

I tried setting it as a cookie but it didn't work:

```
browser
  .setCookie({
    name     : "User_Agent",
    value    : "iphone",
  })
  .url('...')
  // etc
```

Comment: You can configure nightwatch to run tests with different browsers

Answer (score 3):

Your test suite must be independent of the browser targeted.

You should set the user agent directly in the NightWatch configuration json file :

```
"test_settings" : {
  "default" : {
    "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
    "port"  : 4444
    "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
    "silent": true,
    "screenshots" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "path" : "screenshots"
    },
    "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "chromeOptions": {
        "args": [
          "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A",
          "--window-size=320,640"
        ]
      },
      "javascriptEnabled": true,
      "acceptSslCerts": true
    }
  }
```

If necessary, you can find a major list of user agents here : http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/

Answer (score 2):

If anyone here is looking to adjust the user agent string on Firefox, it is a little different to chrome.

```
firefox: {
  ...
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    alwaysMatch: {
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        prefs: {
          'general.useragent.override': 'custom user agent string here',
        },
        args: [],
      },
    },
  },
  ...
},
```

My current package versions:

```
"nightwatch": "^1.3.2"
"geckodriver": "^1.19.1"
```