# nightwatch.js - Sending custom http request headers

Tags: javascript, http-headers, nightwatch.js

I searched around for an answer about this but could'nt find one. I'm using nightwatch.js to write UI-tests. It works fine but I'm in need of sending custom http request headers since the application is protected with digital signage and does not have a login form that the tests can use to access the site itself.

I'm looking for something like this which can be set in PhantomJS but for my nightwatch.json configuration or in the tests themselves.

Is this even possible?

```
    var webPage = require('webpage');
    var page = webPage.create();

    page.customHeaders = {
      "X-Test": "foo",
      "DNT": "1"
    };

    page.onInitialized = function() {
      page.customHeaders = {};
    };
```

Comment: Hi Rhedman,

Have you solved this problem? If solved please put either comment or answer, It will help who are needy.

Comment: did you find solution to this? i am looking for this

Comment: check this : https://eveningsamurai.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/changing-http-headers-for-a-selenium-webdriver-request/

Comment: Might help in some cases - you can set a custom user-agent, so you can at least tell the request came from NightWatch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522757/